# Images loaded via jQuery don't load after first page load

Tags: jquery, image

I'm loading all jpg/png images from a folder and append it to an element and then when the element is "ready" I give it some hover effects and such. However, after the first time I load the page, if I were to refresh it, the images would no longer load. Here's the code I'm using to load the images.

```
var folder = "images/";
$.ajax({
    url: folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, file) {
            if (file.match(/\.(jpe?g|png)$/)) {
                $("div#whatever").append("<img class='gallery' src='"+ folder + file +"'>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Again, it works, but once I refresh the page, it no longer loads them unless I clear my cached images in Chrome. Is there a way I can force a refresh? Would that be the right way to even go about it?

Comment: When you say refresh , are you talking about full page refresh or partial page refresh?

Comment: @Devesh I mean F5. So I'm assuming that's full page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)` this is a random number add it to your image src .. **OR** you may need to try `cache: false` in ajax

```
var folder = "images/";
var RandomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
$.ajax({
    url: folder,
    cache: false,  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, file) {
            if (file.match(/\.(jpe?g|png)$/)) {
                $("div#whatever").append("<img class='gallery' src='"+ folder + file +"?"+RandomNum +"'>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Same thing happens.

Comment: I think the random number to the file should not be required as image caching is good stuff. @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @Devesh you're right but I try to present more than one solution .. the problem is not live for me may be one of them works for him ..  who knows? .. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I tried the cache: false as well but it's still only working after I clear cache. Once I press F5 it disappears. I have the code in the open inside of a a JS file, just above the rest of my code (which is wrapped in a ready function). Perhaps there's something wrong with that? The image loading isn't called in a special function but since I'm refreshing (F5ing) the page, I assume that it'll reload the scripts to. I'm just not understanding how it works the first time after I clear the cached images but then it doesn't after. It must not be executing the load.

Comment: @Devesh It's literally just in a JS file, nothing around it. I call the script in the head of my index.php.